# Opening a QDialog and saving last state

Tags: python, pyqt, qdialog

I am trying to open a `QDialog` from a `QMainWindow`, and after closing the `QDialog, if I need to open it again, it has to open and show the same information that had when I close it.

Here is the code of the `QMainWindow`:

```
class A (QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    #I create a QPushButton to open the QDialog
    self.axes1 = self.figure_canvas.figure.add_axes ([0.8, 0.01, 0.19, 0.05])
    self.button = QPushButton(self.axes1,"Open Dialog")
    self.button.on_clicked(self.OpenDialog)

    #This is the method to open the QDialog which is in another module
  def OpenDialog(self, event):
    text = configurePort.ConfigurePort.retrieve_data(self)
    print text
```

What this code does is create a button in my `QMainWindow` and when I click it, it opens a `QDialog`, which is created in another module. And this is the code of the `QDialog`:

```
class ConfigurePort(QDialog):
  def __init__(self, parent = None):
     QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
     uic.loadUi("configurePort.ui", self)

    #I create a button to check active ports and show them
    self.connect(self.btn_checkconn, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.check_ports)

    #This method calls another class which opens another QDialog
    #and I select the port that I want
  def check_ports(self):
     self.check_serial = CheckPorts(self)
     self.check_serial.exec_()

    #After selecting the port, when I close the QDialog of the class named above
    #the port´s name appears in the first QDialog
  @classmethod
  def retrieve_data(cls, parent = None):
     dlg = cls(parent)
     dlg.exec_()
     text = dlg.getPortText()
     return text

  def closeEvent(self, event):
     #Here is where I need to write the code to close the QDialog 
     #and it does not has to be an event
```

In the method, `closeEvent`, I need to write the necessary code, so I can close the window, and using the same button that I use to open it, open it again with the last information that it showed when I closed it.

I have tried to use `QSettings` but it did not worked (maybe I used it wrong). And I tried the `show()` and `hide()` classes of `PyQt` too, but it did not work. Hope you can help me.

### ----- EDIT -----

I edited the code of above. and I added some methods for a better understanding. So, i open the `QDialog` called `ConfigurePort` and it shows this:

[image]

The red circle, surrounds the port´s name. It is shown in a `QLabel`,and I take this text from the `QDialog` and then print it when I close the `QDialog`. I acomplish this thanks to a question I asked before, wich is in this link:

[Getting data from child using PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302213/getting-data-from-child-using-pyqt/37307475#37307475)

The `check_port` method shown in the code above, opens another `QDialog` that works great. With this I can select the ports that I need in my pc. So, this does not matter.

So, after closing the `QDialog`(and selecting for example "COM3", as you can see in the picture), I need to open it again, and see the same information that was shown before I closed it.

I tried to add this lines, using `QSettings` :

```
self.settings = QSettings("MyCompany", "MyApp")
  if not self.settings.value("windowsState") == None:
    self.restoreState(self.settings.value("windowState"))
```

But as I said before, I think that I did not use it right, but I hope that I solve this using something simpler.

### ----- EDIT 2 -----

Thank to the help of @Brendan Abel I have this code:

```
class ConfigurePort(QDialog):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(ConfigurePort, self).__init__(parent)
    uic.loadUi("configurePort.ui", self)

    self.myValue = 10
    self.restoreSettings()

    self.connect(self.btn_checkconn, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.check_ports)
    self.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel).clicked.connect(self.close)
    self.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok).clicked.connect(self.closeEvent)

    self.iniUi()

  def check_ports(self):
    pass

  def iniUi(self):
    pass #I just create some QLabels in here

  @classmethod
  def retrieve_data(cls, parent = None):
    dlg = cls(parent)
    dlg.exec_()
    text = dlg.getPortText()
    return text

  def closeEvent(self, event):
    self.saveSettings()
    super(QDialog,self).closeEvent(event)

  def saveSettings(self):
    settings = QSettings("MyOrg", "MyApp")
    settings.setValue("myValue", self.myValue)

  def restoreSettings(self):
    settings = QSettings("MyOrg", "MyApp")
    self.myValue = settings.value("myValue", self.myValue)
```

This gives me this error: `TypeError: QWidget.closeEvent(QCloseEvent): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'`
I know that I am missing something, but I can not see it.

Comment: What happened when you used QSettings? what OS are you on?

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you are instantiating `ConfigurePort` as an object, you are just calling the `retrieve_data` method

Comment: How long should the data persist?  Should it open up with the same data if you close and restart your application?  What if the dialog is used by another applications, should both applications have different sets of saved data?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I edited my question for a better understanding. @BrendanAbel , the data only needs to stay until the app is closed, but is better (not necessary) if it stays "forever". And the `QDialog` does not need to be open with another app.

Comment: Are you using the dialog to just display data from the main application or does the user modify data in the dialog? If it is the latter, then you really don't need to get data back from the dialog, just push data up when you open it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways you could persist this data  Generally, to persist data across sessions, you use `QSettings` and load the data in the `__init__` and save it in the `closeEvent` method

Generally it looks something like this.  This also assumes your using the `v2` version of the `QVariant` api; otherwise, the results returned from `QSettings.value` is going to be a `QVariant` and you'll need to cast it to the appropriate python type.  If you're using a recent version of `PyQt` then you should be on `v2`, [but if not you can force it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6238226/1547004) by sticking this at the top of your file

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
sip.setapi('QString', 2)


class MyDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.myvalue = 10
        self.restoreSettings()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.saveSettings()
        super(MyDialog, self).closeEvent(event)

    def saveSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings('myorg', 'myapp')
        settings.setValue('myvalue', self.myvalue)

    def restoreSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings('myorg', 'myapp')
        self.myvalue = settings.value('myvalue', self.myvalue)
```

EDIT:

The error in your code is caused by this:

```
self.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok).clicked.connect(self.closeEvent)
```

You shouldn't be calling or connecting to `closeEvent` directly.  Instead, you should connect to `.close` or `.accept`

```
self.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok).clicked.connect(self.accept)
```

Comment: Handy tip for `QSettings` is when you make the `QApplication`,  use `qApplicationObject.setApplicationName("myapp")`, `qApplicationObject.setOrganizationDomain("myorg.com")` and `qApplicationObject.setOrganizationName("myorg")` (put what you will for `"myapp"` and `"myorg"`) this allows you to call `QSettings()` and not have to specify those in each instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This line: `super(MyDialog, self).closeEvent(event)` , gives me this error : `TypeError: QDialog.closeEvent(QCloseEvent): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'` . What could be the problem? I also think that where you put `MyWidget`, I must put `MyDialog` instead. Thank you again, for all your help

Comment: I'm guessing you're reassigning `event` to a boolean before you call the parent class?

Comment: I edited the question, and I added the code that i have with the one that you wrote above (I use the same variables for now).  That gives me the `TypeError` with the "unexpected bool"

Comment: @PabloFlores Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the `ConfigurePort` class then the `self.configurePortDialog` object should keep consistent. You will need to make sure if you have the user enter data that a cancel does not store the data and that an "ok" stores the data, but I not sure what you are putting in your dialog.

```
class A (QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    #I create a QPushButton to open the QDialog
    self.button = QPushButton("Open Dialog")
    self.button.on_clicked(self.OpenDialog)
    self.configurePortDialog = configurePort.ConfigurePort(parent=self)
    self.configurePortDialog.accepted.connect(self.get_data)

    #This is the method to open the QDialog which is in another module
  def OpenDialog(self, event):
     self.configurePortDialog.show()

  @QtCore.Slot()
  def get_data(self)
    text = self.configurePortDialog.retrieve_data()
    print text
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my question fro a better understanding of what I need to do. Hope you can help me.

Comment: @BrendanAbel Thanks! Fixed

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one question: doesn´t  this line: `text = self.configurePortDialog.retrieve_data()` opens the `QDialog` again?

Comment: Correct, at the time I didn't have the code that showed that you are calling the `exec_()` function in `retrieve_data()` I had wrongly assumed that all it did was return data from the dialog

Comment: @busfault yes, that is all that must do jeje. Retrieve the data that i need from the dialog. So i must take out `dlg.exec_()` ?

Comment: Not necessarily. Also it depends on what you want to do, when you call the exec_() it blocks the current code execution until it returns for more info on modal dialogs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs